# +Accidently sent my BCH from my ledger nano S to a BTC address in Coinbase how can i get it back?

Tags: bitcoin-cash

+Accidently sent my BCH from my ledger nano S to a BTC address in Coinbase and it went thru but never got to my Coinbase account, how can i get it back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to contact Coinbase to retrieve the coins back, because Coinbase hold the private keys on behalf of the users.